# sed command to locate a character in square brackets and perform positional replacement on the numbers following it

Tags: sed

I have a string in my file

```
quipkgkulul,qyyio (avuip),Llo,tyiop :           D[0x000]:   0x00123400  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

i want to locate `D[0x000]` and replace positions in the digits following the colon (all of them) at different positions.

the final result should look like

```
quipkgkulul,qyyio (avuip),Llo,tyiop :           D[0x000]:   0x00xxx00  0x000xxx0  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

i tried

```
sed -E 's/[^[][a-zA-Z0-9][^]]//g' file
```

which separates out the numbers from the brackets

Comment: Position of `xxx` is neither consistent, nor obvious. Do you want to replace `1234` with `xxx` (3 `x` instead of 4 digits)? Or is it mistake in the example?

Comment: Your attempt doesn't take you very far, and mostly just demonstrates that `sed` is probably not the tool you are looking for. This would seem moderately easy with Awk but your requirements are not clear enough to venture into attempting to provide an answer.

Comment: the want to locate  "0x00123400  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000" each of these from the file and perform positional replacement on any of those 4 columns at any positions

Comment: @vidya what do you mean by "any position"?

Comment: by "any position" i mean i could pick any of those 4 hex numbers and choose to replace any digit on those numbers with x"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want what is described in example, you can use this command:

```bash
sed -E 's/(D\[0x[[:digit:]]{3}\]:[[:space:]]+0x[[:digit:]]{2})[[:digit:]]{4}([[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]+0x[[:digit:]]{3})[[:digit:]]{4}([[:digit:]]{1})/\1xxx\2xxx\3/g' file
```

It will find every block of the following format:

```
D[0x000]:   0x00123400  0x00000000
    ^^^       ^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^ 
                ||||         ||||
```

where `^` marks any digit, `|` symbols that will be replaced with `xxx`.

Explanation of matching pattern:

- `(D\[0x[[:digit:]]{3}\]:[[:space:]]+0x[[:digit:]]{2})` matches block before first replaced segment. Later referenced in replacement string as `\1`. Here:

  - `D\[0x[[:digit:]]{3}\]:` matches strings like `D[0x000]:` where last three zeros can be any digits,
  - `[[:space:]]+` matches any positive umber of whitespace symbols,
  - `0x[[:digit:]]{2}` matches first part of first hex address, like `0x00`, where last two zeros can be any digit.
- `[[:digit:]]{4}` any four digits that later will be replaced with `xxx`,
- `([[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]+0x[[:digit:]]{3})` matches second group (`\2`). Two digits, spaces, `0x`, three digits.
- `[[:digit:]]{4}` second replaced segment,
- `([[:digit:]]{1})` last digit, referenced as `\3`.

Comment: this command does the replacement as i expected. but im not clear how the digits {2},{4} etc were arrived at. wanted clarity on it

Comment: was seeking explanation on this command

Comment: @vidya, Added explanation to the answer.

Comment: i tried modifying the command to replace  different posistions in this string like  D[0x000]:   0x00123400  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000                      D[0x000]:   0x00123400  0x00000000  0xxxxxx00  0x0000000x. it tried altering "[[:digit:]]{4}" this part with different digits but i dont see the replacement. could u suggest how can i alter this.

Comment: @vidya, to replace those you'll need `s/(D\[0x[[:digit:]]{3}\]:[[:space:]]+0x[[:digit:]]{8}[[:space:]]+0x[[:digit:]]{8}[[:space:]]+0x)[[:digit:]]{6}([[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]+0x[[:digit:]]{7})[[:digit:]]{1}/\1xxxxx\2x/g`

Comment: is there any generic way to do this?

Comment: If you'll use something like perl or python - you can catch every digit in it's own group and replace only those that you want, like in my answer to your previous question. In `sed` though you're are limited to only 9 groups, and in this exact case there is no obvious generic case for your task. @vidya

Comment: my file contains a number of lines such as:

Comment: my file contains a number of lines such as:D[0x000]: 0x00120001 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000                                                                                                         D[0x010]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x12340000 0x00000000 0x00000000       aD[0x020]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 etc. how can use the first part to the command provided by you to uniquely identify D[0x000],D[0x010],D[0x020] etc i believe to replace the other parts of the line i can use the earlier method suggested by you

Comment: s/(D\[0x[[:digit:]]{3}\]:[[:space:]]+0x[[:digit:]]{8}[[:space:]]+0x[[:digit:]]{8}[[:space:]]+0x)[[:digit:]]{6}([[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]+0x[[:digit:]]{7})[[:digit:]]{1}/\1xxxxx\2x/g how can i modify this command to replace  D[0x000]: 0x00123400 0x00000000 0x12345000 0x00000000 D[0x000]: 0x00123400 0x00000000 0xxxxxx00 0x00000000. i tried some modifications but didnt work could you suggest a appropriate command

Comment: @vidya, dude, go [here](https://regex101.com/r/Q73rGJ/1) or [here](https://sed.js.org/) and test your substitutions. Don't expect that SO will provide you regex for every case: this is not free code writing site after all.